# DARKNET/OPENCV/GSTREAMER: module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to run the Yolov4-tiny demo of Darknet but am encountering the following error:

```
[WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage openCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate required memory.
```

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 4B with 4GB RAM running Bullseye and have the Raspberry Pi Camera Module v2 as a camera (which works in general).
I think that the hardware limitation might be a problem here (128 MB VRAM allocated) and that the standard resolution set by OpenCV might be too much for the Pi. If anyone could at least point me at how to set the resolution in OpenCV (haven't found very helpful results online yet), I would be very grateful.

Answer (score -1):

In similar situation with gstreamer I have to add

dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

to config.txt